# Guestbook app deployment error cloud SQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

app engine log says
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://173.194.111.127:3306/Guestbook

Help says make sure appengine-web.xml includes true which is the last line before  in my file.  I could use some help getting this connection to work.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that you should check:

- Please make sure that the MySQL JAR file is present in your `WEB-INF\lib` directory.
- Once that is done, you can ensure that you enable the MySQL/ConnectorJ (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#enable_connector_j). As mentioned in the document, go to `war\WEB-INF` folder. You will find the `appengine-web.xml` file. Inside this file, enable the JAR file as given below:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

`<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">`

...

`<use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>`

...

`</appengine-web-app>`

Comment: Still getting error "Uncaught exception from servlet
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://173.194.111.127:3306/Guestbook "I added mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar to the lib directory, it was not there.  This is my apengine-web.xml file condensed <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>nsldevtest</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
  <system-properties>
    <prop/>
  </sys..es>
</appengine-web-app>.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#Java_Connect_to_your_database) you should only be using the "jdbc:mysql" connection string for local development.  For running on appengine you should use jdbc:google:mysql.